# Can we use MSMQ in .NET6

Tags: console, .net-6.0, msmq

In.NET 6 (C# 10), I'm creating a console/worker service. In order to store and retrieve messages, I intend to use Microsoft Message Queuing. Like when one service queues up a message and another service retrieves it from the queue. Recently, I read that MSMQ would no longer be supported in.net core. Is it real? any additional service we might utilize for the same purpose (other than Azure).

Comment: You could always build your own .NET library for MSMQ: it’s just a matter of P/Invoking the Win32/MSMQ APIs. There’s also plenty of reimplementations on NuGet already, e.g. https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSMQ.Messaging

Answer (score 1):

`System.Messaging` (MSMQ) is not supported in the .net ecosystem. You will have to use an alternative message broked such as:

- RabbitMQ - https://www.rabbitmq.com/
- Kafka - https://developer.confluent.io/get-started/dotnet/

If you're locked in to MSMQ, I think there are experimental MSMQ bridges out there for .net but they won't have official support.